# What is the "apt" equivalent of the zypper search command? Im trying to search for a specific pkg without having to scroll through every pkg

Tags: command-line, apt, search, flatpak, appimage

So before when I was using openSUSE, the one thing I liked about zypper was the simple
`zypper search [keyword]` command that made it so easy to find a installed app. But for apt, I have yet to find one that is on the same level as zypper search. I have tried `apt search [keyword]` , `apt-cache search [keyword]` &    `apt-file search [keyword]` but for some reason it wont find appimages or flatpaks that I know for a fact are installed. (atleast as far as I know, I am a command line newbie so Im pretty ignorant to it all). Maybe Im asking for too much but if you can help me out or point me in the right direction, that would be rad.

Thanks in advance

[This picture is an example of the zypper command at work with a little explanation on what it does, hopefully that will help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1UGf.png)

Comment: `apt` is for *deb* packages only, and doesn't find other packages; `snap search` will search for snaps etc...

Comment: ehmmm it is not the same as this one https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/zypper.8.html ? :)

Comment: Does Zypper support searching for flatpaks and snaps? I thought it was RPM only

Comment: @muru ah ok that makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

The command line equivalent is

```
apt search <string>
```

Just like `zypper` searches for packages in the OpenSuse packaging system, so does `apt` for the Debian package management system used by Ubuntu.

Search other packages using the dedicated tools, e.g. `snap search` to search Snap packages, or `flatpak search` for flatpak packages. If you consistenly name your AppImages, e.g., they all have an `.AppImage` extension, then it suffices to search for the `*.AppImage` files you placed on your system to find the installed ones. To search AppImages, you will have to go to the web. Many are indexed on https://www.appimagehub.com/, but essentially there is no central location you could query with a terminal command here.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are searching for is:

```
sudo apt list <packagename> --installed
```

This will only list either automatically or manually installed packages.
If you do not know the exact name, I tend to use:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep -i *something*
```

Usually gets me close to what I need.